# Building a MySQL query from optional filters in Express JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Sorry if it's a dumb question but I'm new to express and MySQL and I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

I need to create a MySQL query based on some user input filters from an HTML form.
The parameters are something like this:

```js
let sDate = req.body.startDate;
let eDate = req.body.endDate;
let param1 = req.body.param1;
let param2 = req.body.param2;
let param3 = req.body.param3;
let param4 = req.body.param4;
```

A normal query that I will use if all params are not null will be

```js
const query = `
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
date BETWEEN ? AND ?
AND col1 = ?
AND col2 = ?
AND col3 = ?
AND col4 = ?;`

db.query(query, [startDate, endDate, param1, param2, param3, param4], (e, rows)=>{});
```

But every single parameter can be null, so there are a lot of possible filter combinations.

Is there a way to query the db with one single query? I could handle it in many if-else statements but it feels wrong.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: With respect, you did not tell us enough about your question for us to help. Please [edit] it, or ask another.Your SQL will query a table: please show it to us. And please explain how your four `param` values express the criteria for searching. The interface between the procedural (javascript) realm and the declarative (SQL) realm requires a lot of precision.

Comment: @O.Jones sorry about that! I've edited with a  query that I would use in a scenario that all parameters are provided. What I'm kinda looking for is if there's a way to create a query that does not take into consideration null values in a WHERE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your `col1 = ?` pattern you can use `(? IS NULL OR ? = col1)`.

For your date matching you can do this.

```sql
   WHERE date <= IF( ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE '2999-12-31')
     AND date >= IF( ? IS NOT NULL THEN ? ELSE '1000-01-01')
```

But notice that parameters appear twice. So your query is

```js
const sql = `
SELECT *
  FROM tbl
 WHERE date <= IF(? IS NOT NULL, ?, '2999-12-31')
   AND date >= IF(? IS NOT NULL, ?, '1000-01-01')
   AND (? IS NULL OR col1 = ?)
   AND (? IS NULL OR col2 = ?)
   AND (? IS NULL OR col3 = ?)
   AND (? IS NULL OR col4 = ?);`
```

And you'll invoke it like this.

```js
const params = [startDate, startDate, 
                endDate, endDate,
                param1, param1, 
                param2, param3, 
                param2, param3, 
                param4, param4]

db.query(query, params, (e, rows)=>{});
```

But **beware**: this kind of query is a notorious edge case for the query-optimization software in the database server. It can't tell what you want well enough to use table statistics to choose the right index.  Still, be sure to put an index on

```
(date, col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

for this query. You're likely to have a date range.

This may be slow, especially if that table is really large. You may be better off building up a custom query from strings each time you handle the request. The query optimizer understands stuff like this better than stuff with that `? IS NULL OR` clause in there.

```sql
WHERE date <= ?
  AND date >= ?
  AND col2 = ?
  AND col3 = ?
```

Comment: I've used `IF(? IS NOT NULL, ?, '1000-01-01')`

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks for pointing out my mistake. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `LIKE` clause with a combination of the `COALESCE()` function and the `NULLIF()` function to prevent a NULL value from being passed to the LIKE clause

```
const query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE name LIKE COALESCE(NULLIF(?, ''), '%')";
const values = [name];
```